# Custom Date Picker in Android

Tags: android, datepicker

I am new in Android.I am trying to create an application where in I need to have a Dialog with 2 edit text and one date picker.So what is the best possible way to use date picker.In a fragement or with Alert Dialog.Please share the example.

Answer (score 0):

you create a layout and add what you want.

than use that

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getContext());
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog_layout);
//create your edittext and date picker
dialog.show
```

that's all

and you can use this library for datepicker https://github.com/code-troopers/android-betterpickers

Answer (score 0):

Refer these link for your query
 [link1](https://github.com/ctake0005/DatePickerDialogSample) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30987181/date-picker-inside-custom-dialog-in-android)